# Laravel redirects resources to https on localhost and got 404

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I set up xampp apache on macos.

Added to httpd-vhosts.conf to have separated url from my other projects

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@abc.local
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/abc_web/public"
    ServerName abc.local
    ServerAlias www.abc.local
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/abc_web/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/abc.local-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/abc.local-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

also on hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   abc.local
```

But after this all my assets tying to load over HTTPS
and getting 404

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

When I open it direct on browser over HTTP `http://abc.local/js/app.js` it loads without any problem.

Also when I `run php artisan serve` and go to `localhost:8000` everything is ok.

I don't understand why.

Comment: Hey! Did you try to edit the .env file with the correct url? :D

Comment: Yes already APP_URL=`http://abc.local`